# how to display all data in the left table only once and display matching data on the right table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to display all data in the left table only once and display matching data on the right table.

table 1

```
id        name
1       abc
2       cdr 
3       sdf
4       asew
5       sda
6       few
7       asdq
8       uio
9       kjh
```

table 2

```
id        table1_id      table2_name
1            1              test1
2            2              test1
3            3              test1
4            4              test1
5            1              test2
6            2              test2
7            3              test2
8            4              test2
```

I want to display all the data in table1 only once and display all matching data from table2 where table2_name is equal to 'test1'

table1_2

```
table1_name     table2_name
abc               test1
cdr               test1
sdf               test1
asew              test1
sda               null
few               null
asdq              null
uio               null
kjh               null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.name, t2.min_table2_name 
from table1 t1 left join 
(select t2.table1_id, min(t2.table2_name) min_table2_name
    from table2 t2
    group by t2.table1_id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

or if you want to only show a certain table2_name value

```
select t1.name, t2.min_table2_name 
from table1 t1 left join 
(select t2.table1_id, min(t2.table2_name) min_table2_name
    from table2 t2
    where t2.table2_name = 'test1'
    group by t2.table1_id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

Comment: im having problem I cannot select the second table using the first select statement. on this part "select t1.name, t2.min_table2_name " error was saying that unknown column t2.min_table2_name.

Comment: not sure but I just removed the alias on the table name and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL, but it is not a simple `left outer join`.  The key is reducing `table2` to get only the first occurrence for each `id`.  The following uses the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select t1.name as table1_name, t2.table2_name
from table1 t1 left outer join
     (select table1_id,
             substring_index(group_concat(table2_name order by id asc), ',', 1) as table2_name
      from table2 t2
      group by table2_name
     ) t2
     on t2.table1_id = t1.id;
```

Comment: it didn't gave a result same as my example above. it result like this

`table1_name  table2_name
abc           test1,test2
cdr           test1,test2`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
SELECT  A.name, B.table2_name
FROM    [table 1] A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  [table1_id],MAX(table2_name) [table2_name]
FROM    [table 2]) B
ON  A.id = B.[table1_id]
```

Comment: how can I filter it like display table2_name == 'test1' like the sample above